# WPF UI Update from excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, multithreading, user-interface

I've got a Loading page that starts up (typically I have my home page load it on startup but I've swapped it recently). I have an excel file with tons of data in it. I have a class for dumping that data. I also have a class for each of the lists I want to create. The loading page should be updating it's percentage as it goes.

I was able to get it to work in the example below.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public MainController main = new MainController();
    public ExcelImporter tempExcel = new ExcelImporter();
    List<Character.MainRace> listRaces = new List<Character.MainRace>();
    List<string> tempString = new List<string>();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBarTest.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        textBlockPercent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
        textBlockTest.Text = (string)e.UserState;
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        tempExcel.Create();
        tempExcel.SetSheet("Races");
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        worker.ReportProgress(0, String.Format("Process Iteration 1."));
        List<string> myRaceName = tempExcel.GetRangeValue("A2", "A46");
        List<string> myRaceShortDescription = tempExcel.GetRangeValue("N2", "N46");
        for (int raceSelection = 0; raceSelection < myRaceName.Count - 1; raceSelection++)
        {
            Character.MainRace tempRace = new Character.MainRace();
            tempRace.Race = myRaceName[raceSelection];
            double percentage = ((double)raceSelection / (double)myRaceName.Count) * 100.0;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            worker.ReportProgress((int)percentage, String.Format("Processing " + myRaceName[raceSelection]));
            tempRace.ShortDescription = myRaceShortDescription[raceSelection];
            listRaces.Add(tempRace);
        }
        worker.ReportProgress(100, "Done Processing");
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
        progressBarTest.Value = 0;
        textBlockTest.Text = "";
    }
}
```

There's really two places where I need the UI to update. Each time I'm loading a new set of data for each loader like Human, elf, etc for race and fighter, paladin, thief, etc for class. As well as when I move on to the next set of data like Classes Race, Feats, etc. (though to keep this a bit shorter I only included showing just 1 for race.

I'm pretty new to coding in general especially wpf. I've been going through bits a pieces of tutorials. I've tried using INotifyproperty,background worker, dispatcher, binding and not binding the content. I'm just not getting it. Everything works separately but not together. From what I understand, it's because the UI thread which is the main thread getting held up because of my long process.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I removed a lot of the complexity to make it more straightforward. I have a value and a border that I would like to adjust. The adjustment should happen whenever the racecompiler hits a new race in it's loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen mentioned, we need an example.  You're trying to update a WPF UI based on the contents of [*cringe*] hard-coded Excel ranges.  I'm guessing the workbook import part works, but the UI is freezing? or not updating?

First, try using a `DataGrid` to display your data on the UI.  Bind its `ItemsSource` to a `List` (or `ObservableCollection`) of a class that holds all your pertinent data nicely.  The `DataGrid` should do the rest as the `AutoGenerateColumns` is true by default.

Then, for further help, you'll have to attempt something and provide a reproducible example of what's failing.  Showing the implementation of your `BackgroundWorker` would provide some clues on holding the main UI thread.

Comment: I'll switch over to a database in the future. For now I'm using excel just to make testing easier, as I'm scraping the data and dumping it to excel.

Comment: And that's fine.  But the original question was regarding the _WPF UI update_.  `DataGrid` provides a simple way of displaying all your Excel data.  Without any clear example of what your UI is doing, we can't help.

Comment: "The loading page should be updating it's percentage as it goes." I wanted my custom progress bar UI to update as it moved through each file. Thought I had made that clear.

Comment: > Showing the implementation of your `BackgroundWorker` would provide some clues on holding the main UI thread.  It's probably not updating because you're holding the UI thread.  I recently upgraded my projects from `BackgroundWorker` to `Task.Run`.  I'd recommend it here as well.